# Example of Nonrectifiable Curve with integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

Let D be a domain. Is there any non-rectifiable curve C with parametrization $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow C$ such that for every analytic function $f: D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $C\subset D$ the following sum converges?
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\gamma(c_k))(\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1}))$$
where $c_k\in [t_{k-1},t_{k}]$ and $t_k$ are the partition of $[a,b]$. In other words, every analytic function $f$ is contour integrable over $C$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does it mean to integrate over a non rectifiable curve?

Comment: It means Riemann Sum to converge.

Comment: I am editting the question now.

Comment: can you write an example of a curve and what do you mean by Riemann sum without having a sum of the type $f(\gamma(\zeta)(\gamma'(t_i)-(\gamma'(t_{i+1}))$ that requires some kind of derivative for the parameterization of the curve?

Comment: Maybe the phrase "contour integral" is what you want to add to your question? If so, I found it interesting that even Wikipedia restricts itself to piecewise differentiable curves. It feels like people really like contour integrals mostly for the residue theorem, and skip over the possibility of non rectifiable curves. I'll be curious to see if you get any responses.

Comment: Yes I mean contour integral. I have updated the question.

Comment: By Cauchy–Goursat theorem I think a closed non-rectifiable curve will have an integral 0 (probably) and it will be a counterexample. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: I think this will involve checking the core theorems of complex analysis, seeing which ones assume regularity of the contour (it seems like a lot!), digging into the proofs to see if/where the regularity is used, and seeing if that's a place to build a counter example. And I think I'll leave that up to others. :-)

Comment: What you ask is not the usual definition of a contour integral. - for example it depends on the parametrization and is essentially a regular integral wr to the measure $\gamma(t)dt$ on $[0,1]$ so has nothing really to do with curve integrals in the usual sense

Comment: Can you give me an example that shows the dependence on parametrization?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=1$ is an analytic function, so, while I don't fully understand your question, I'm going to guess that once you've clarified the details the answer will be "no".

Comment: $f(x)=1$ does not work. Since Rieman Sum becomes $\sum x_i-x_{i-1}$ whereas the rectifiability sum is $\sum |x_i-x_{i-1}|$.

Comment: Not if you're talking about a line integral. There are multiple "integrals over a curve", especially if you are dealing with complex functions, as your use of "analytic" hints at. Please make your question more precise.

Comment: Its complex integral.